# How to create Dockerfile properly for project that references Dll project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget

First, I have used search and they mostly seem to have information on net core v1 or v2. I'm currently running 7 and there has been some differences between few versions, especially after 2-3 how to create the Dockerfile.

So I have my API project referencing other DLL project in the same folder.

Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy everything
COPY . ./
# Restore as distinct layers
RUN dotnet restore myApiSubFolder
# Build and publish a release
RUN dotnet publish myApiSubFolder -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
COPY myApiSubFolder/version.txt .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myAPi.dll"]
EXPOSE 5000
```

I'm able to to build it and when restoring the projecc that references the other one, it will perform restore to that as well when you look a the logs. However I get spammed a MUCH about some errors not restoring the DLL project, but the app seems to work.

Here are the few logs of the docker huild omitted by the warning spam:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  61.87MB

Step 1/11 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build-env
7.0: Pulling from dotnet/sdk
8740c948ffd4: Already exists
cad0782184b4: Pulling fs layer
6dccfb169955: Pulling fs layer
e9ed4dc59fb6: Pulling fs layer
39700a6fea9c: Pulling fs layer
114e89b63164: Pulling fs layer
02c80deb05b5: Pulling fs layer
4ef1d2118a2b: Pulling fs layer
39700a6fea9c: Waiting
114e89b63164: Waiting
02c80deb05b5: Waiting
4ef1d2118a2b: Waiting
e9ed4dc59fb6: Download complete
39700a6fea9c: Verifying Checksum
39700a6fea9c: Download complete
cad0782184b4: Verifying Checksum
cad0782184b4: Download complete
6dccfb169955: Verifying Checksum
6dccfb169955: Download complete
4ef1d2118a2b: Verifying Checksum
4ef1d2118a2b: Download complete
114e89b63164: Verifying Checksum
114e89b63164: Download complete
02c80deb05b5: Verifying Checksum
02c80deb05b5: Download complete
cad0782184b4: Pull complete
6dccfb169955: Pull complete
e9ed4dc59fb6: Pull complete
39700a6fea9c: Pull complete
114e89b63164: Pull complete
02c80deb05b5: Pull complete
4ef1d2118a2b: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:c99629b03411c7b0aa5324abd01147c8a971a8c19b6ff0b570b62d8d576b1bfa
Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0
 ---> b2061e2c2b3c
Step 2/11 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in dfc8f1512574
Removing intermediate container dfc8f1512574
 ---> 0eb580a4456b
Step 3/11 : COPY . ./
 ---> b27eed30f259
Step 4/11 : RUN dotnet restore ApiProject
 ---> Running in a510cc167168
  Determining projects to restore...
  Restored /app/DllProject/DllProject.csproj (in 2.17 sec).
  Restored /app/ApiProject/ApiProject.csproj (in 2.17 sec).
Removing intermediate container a510cc167168
 ---> 4266cc65baee
Step 5/11 : RUN dotnet publish ApiProject -c Release -o out
 ---> Running in b678b3120d93
MSBuild version 17.4.1+9a89d02ff for .NET
  Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore.
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): w**arning NETSDK1004: Assets file'/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore/2.2.0/lib/netst> .. not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file. [/app/DllProject/DllProject.csproj]**
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): warning NETSDK1004: Assets file '/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.antiforgery/2.2>
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): warning NETSDK1004: Assets file '/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.>
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): warning NETSDK1004: Assets file '/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.>
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): warning NETSDK1004: Assets file '/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization/2>
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): warning NETSDK1004: Assets file '/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.authorization.p>
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): warning NETSDK1004: Assets file '/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.connections.abs>
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): warning NETSDK1004: Assets file '/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.cors/2.2.0/lib/>
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): warning NETSDK1004: Assets file '/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.cryptography.in>
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): warning NETSDK1004: Assets file '/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.dataprotection/>
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): warning NETSDK1004: Assets file '/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.dataprotection.>
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): warning NETSDK1004: Assets file '/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.diagnostics/2.2>
/usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.102/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): warning NETSDK1004: Assets file '/root/.nuget/packages/microsoft.aspnetcore.diagnostics.abs>
............... many pages of this!
DllProject -> /app/DllProject/bin/Release/net7.0/DllProject.dll
  ApiProject -> /app/ApiProject/bin/Release/net7.0/ApiProject.dll
  ApiProject -> /app/out/
Removing intermediate container b678b3120d93
 ---> a7aea5cc640c
Step 6/11 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0
7.0: Pulling from dotnet/aspnet
8740c948ffd4: Already exists
cad0782184b4: Already exists
6dccfb169955: Already exists
e9ed4dc59fb6: Already exists
39700a6fea9c: Already exists
Digest: sha256:b017897d7702fd57ce869914c486ff5650b33c4821a343af1bf53cee3dc8fa03
Status: Downloaded newer image for mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0
 ---> b8052dbd4482
Step 7/11 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in 455823352c8c
Removing intermediate container 455823352c8c
 ---> a934337e89a8
Step 8/11 : COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
 ---> e8c328d43d94
Step 9/11 : COPY ApiProject/version.txt .
 ---> a64708e99fb8
Step 10/11 : ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "ApiProject.dll"]
 ---> Running in eed9fa6d4b12
Removing intermediate container eed9fa6d4b12
 ---> baa1bb744983
Step 11/11 : EXPOSE 5000
 ---> Running in d12bc15b7a44
Removing intermediate container d12bc15b7a44
 ---> beae19bc450d
Successfully built beae19bc450d
```

So everything seems to work, logs show that both projects has been restored but I'm never comforttable with random warnings or errors even though it works.

How should be this done with .NET Core 7?

Comment: Have you tried the publish way with .NET 7? [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/docker/publish-as-container). Works with just one command: ```dotnet publish --os linux --arch x64 /t:PublishContainer -c Release``` and you don't need a docker file at all ;)

Comment: I actuually saw that but didn't give it a try yet. I have so many personal/work projects and this is a first 7. I prefer Dockerfiles but I guess I have to take look again ;)

Comment: I got it working, but I can't find anywhere how to add files to be copied into the imge, which is essential for me. Any ideas? Nothing mentioned in docs.

For docker-compose, you probably can't do "build: ./src" anymore but instead have to create the image and reference to that image instead. Not a big deal but strange that they don't mention anything about copying files. It's just a small .txt file in the root fo the project.

Comment: I had multiple issues when trying to work with this, probably misconfiguration between .csproj container settings. Anyway I had hard time to get the project updated if I had those settings defined in .csproj.

Another issue is that I could not find any docs or way to add files directly to the image in build-phase.

It's somewhat confusing as they have docker-compose stuff as well.

Will stick to the dockerfiles for now, but atleast I didn't get any random warnings during building the container.

Comment: Ok yes was just an idea. For me its working fine but I do not need any additional files in my image.